# How to export list of lists with different sizes in r

Tags: r

I researched ways to write this type of list, but I could not achieve.

Here is my data:

```
a<-structure(list(X2005 = structure(list(hours = list(c(0.2, 0, 
4), c(0.2, 4)), maxx = structure(list(maxh2 = 4, maxh3 = 4), .Names = c("maxh2", 
"maxh3"))), .Names = c("hours", "maxx")), X2006 = structure(list(
    hours = list(c(1.8, 0, 1), c(1.8, 1)), maxx = structure(list(
        maxh2 = 1.8, maxh3 = 1.8), .Names = c("maxh2", "maxh3"
    ))), .Names = c("hours", "maxx")), X2007 = structure(list(
    hours = list(c(4.2, 0, 0), c(4.2, 0)), maxx = structure(list(
        maxh2 = 4.2, maxh3 = 4.2), .Names = c("maxh2", "maxh3"
    ))), .Names = c("hours", "maxx")), X2008 = structure(list(
    hours = list(c(0.1, 6, 0), c(3.1, 3)), maxx = structure(list(
        maxh2 = 6, maxh3 = 3.1), .Names = c("maxh2", "maxh3"))), .Names = c("hours", 
"maxx"))), .Names = c("X2005", "X2006", "X2007", "X2008"))
```

I need to see this list of lists in a excel sheet.

Comment: Maybe turn it into a csv with `write.csv`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could try this:

```
write.csv(do.call("rbind",list(unlist(a))),"testme.csv")
```

You could also try this and do some `reshape2`ing before export.

```
write.csv(do.call("cbind",list(unlist(a))),"testme2.csv")
```

Viewing the structure these yield:

```
View(do.call("cbind",list(unlist(a))))
```

Another option as suggested by @jay.sf :

```
openxlsx::write.xlsx(do.call("rbind",list(unlist(a))),"testme.xlsx")
```